# passing the path params with object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a partial from which I need to call a route which will have a controller and a view of its own. When I call the route, I also need to pass a json object to the controller. I have done this earlier for simple values like id, name etc but in that case, I passed it as path param and I can retrieve it using the $routeparams.  But how to do the same with json object. Please let me know.

Comment: By 'partial' you mean including a template with ng-incluce, directive template or with $routeProvider?

Comment: partial is the html template for a route. Here I am interested in calling a route from a partial and be able to pass the json object for the next controller mapped for the subsequent route.

Comment: So you have a scope that is being created in one controller which has an action that allows to change a route but you would like to pass data from this scope to another scope that will be created on that target controller? In that case service is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a factory to save data from one controller and retrieve it from an other controller.

Something like this?

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('mySerivce', function() {
           var jsonData;
           return {
               setData: function(data) {
                   jsonData = data;
               },
               getData: function() {
                   return jsonData;
               }
           }
    });
```

setData from the first controller and from the second getData.

Comment: Thanks @LooMan. Is this the best way to get this done. Could you please let me know since there can be multiple request and how to map data for each corresponding request.

Comment: Yeah I think the factory solution is the best and the simplest way to get this done. Can you just save the json object in the factory, and let the controller decide what to do with the data?

Comment: So we need to store the data with a key in the factory and pass the key when routing. The Controller configured for the route will use the key to fetch the data from the factory? Is this what you meant to implement?